# How to separate rows belonging together from each others

Tags: php, html, sql, rows

I think my question won't be any complicated for you, I'm just a noob. (however, working on it)

I have a table in my .db, which looks like this:

| Number | Text | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31156 | From Team **A** to Team **B** : Player X0 | 11.01.2021 21:07:56 |
| 31155 | From Team **B** to Team **A** : Player Y7 | 11.01.2021 21:07:56 |
| 31034 | From Team **X** to Team **F** : Player Z3 | 06.01.2021 20:16:40 |
| 30472 | From Team **C** to Team **D** : Player Q1 | 18.12.2020 20:55:45 |
| 30471 | From Team **D** to Team **C** : Player P5 | 18.12.2020 20:55:45 |
| 30406 | From Team **L** to Team **M** : Player 9F | 15.12.2020 21:29:24 |
| 30405 | From Team **M** to Team **L** : Player Y4 | 15.12.2020 21:29:24 |
| 30322 | From Team **U** to Team **W** : Player 8A | 12.12.2020 20:55:15 |
| 30321 | From Team **W** to Team **U** : Player Z2 | 12.12.2020 20:55:15 |

As you can see, there are transactions from Team X to Team Y and vice versa, while mostly there are 2 transactions belonging to each other (transaction asset for asset) - exception here is No. 31034 (it's simply just asset for free). These transactions belonging to each other always have **same DateTime**, while **Number is always x+1**.

To print all results I use this:

```
$Query = "SELECT LeagueLog.* 
FROM LeagueLog 
WHERE LeagueLog.TransactionType = 1 
ORDER BY LeagueLog.Number DESC";

$Transaction = $db->query($Query);
if (empty($Transaction) == false){while ($row = $Transaction ->fetchArray()) {  

echo "<header class=\"contentItem__header\" style=border-top-color:#cbccce><a class=\"contentItem__header__wrapper\" ><div  class=\"contentItem__logo\" style=display:-webkit-inline-box;line-height:20px;color:#1d1e1f;font-weight:600;font-size:13px;width:75%>" .$row['Text'] . " (" .$row['DateTime'].")" . "</div><div  class=\"teamLogo--fancy\" style=background-color:#cbccce></div></a></header>\n"; /* The \n is for a new line in the HTML Code */
```

My question is, if there is a way to separate transactions belonging together from each others (= not having them in one column without space). I think, it's possible since there is always the same DateTime and Number difference +/- 1, but unfortunately I have no clue how can I do it...

I thought about adding a `</br>` to separate each row and then to add condition saying something like: “if DateTime result already exist in column, remove `</br>`.“ Then I would be able to achieve the desired result of:

```
Trade : From team A to team B
Trade : From team B to team A

Trade : From team C to team D
Trade : From team D to team C

Trade : From team X to team A
Trade : From team A to team X

Trade : From team Y to team P

Trade : From team N to team L
Trade : From team L to team N
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would help if you followed basic database design: [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), store a single piece of info in each column

Comment: It's done now. Sorry

Comment: You haven't changed anything??

Comment: Now? Maybe I don't know what you mean...

Comment: Did you read that Wikipedia article? You are storing 3 pieces of info in a single column, `TeamFrom, TeamTo, Player` and you need to parse them out before you re-ask this question

Comment: Yes I did read. But this is how it's in my table, look : https://i.ibb.co/Br5zrcd/question.png

Comment: Sort your table out then. As to your problem, if you can describe exactly how you want these transactions separated or grouped then we could do something. Not clear at the moment what you want to do with duplicate records

Comment: These pieces of info are automatically generated by my simulator, I can't do anything about that. 

I think I described it in detail what I need. I want to separate it BY DATETIME, which is always the same for the rows belonging together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying you want to group them by date, and get the two values next to each other in columns, instead of one row after another. We don't need to split out the `Text` here because we only ever have two rows

```sql
SELECT
    Number = MIN(l.Number),
    FirstTransaction  = MIN(l.Text),
    SecondTransaction = CASE WHEN MIN(l.Text) <> MAX(l.Text) THEN MAX(l.Text) END,
    l.DateTime
FROM LeagueLog l
WHERE l.TransactionType = 1
GROUP BY DateTime
ORDER BY MIN(LeagueLog.Number) DESC;
```

Comment: No results are print.

Comment: None at all? That's impossible unless you have no rows that satisfy the `WHERE TransactionType = 1`, which incidentally, is straight from your code, I have no idea what it means

Comment: TransactionType = 1 is alright, there is no problem. Just tell me, should I copy your code word by word? (l.Number or LeagueLog.Number, l.Text or LeagueLog.Text)? Sorry I'm noob.

Comment: Whichever. I aliased the table `l`, you must take out the alias if you want to use the full name

Comment: This doesn't work for me: 
`$Query = "SELECT
    LeagueLog.Number = MIN(LeagueLog.Number),
    FirstTransaction  = MIN(LeagueLog.Text),
    SecondTransaction = CASE WHEN MIN(LeagueLog.Text) <> MAX(LeagueLog.Text) THEN MAX(LeagueLog.Text) END,
    LeagueLog.DateTime
FROM LeagueLog
GROUP BY DateTime
ORDER BY MIN(LeagueLog.Number) DESC";`

Comment: What happens if you run it in SSMS?

Comment: Still not working. There must be something wrong within the code I guess.

Comment: Problem is with ''First Transaction'' and ''Second Transaction''. It's nothing like that in my .db. Can you help me?

Comment: What does that mean? Please describe the problem clearly. By the way, which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySQL/MariaDB? Postgres?